# Make toolbar transparent?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-toolbar

I want to make my toolbar transparent.
I found some answers, but they didn't help me.
My Toolbar white instead transparent
Here is my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:foxrey="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      foxrey:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
      foxrey:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
      android:background="@color/transparent"
      foxrey:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText.Inverse"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
```

Here is ActionBarThemeOverlay:

```
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
   <item name="colorControlNormal">?actionBarIconColor</item>
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
   <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
   <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

</style>
```

I also tried this theme:

```
<style name="ToolbarTransparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="android:background">@color/tranp</item>
   <item name="background">@color/tranp</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
   <item name="colorControlNormal">?actionBarIconColor</item>
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
   <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

But it doesn't work.

This is what I have now:

[image]

I want to get this:

[image]

Comment: what is the value of @color/transparent?

Comment: @user3290180 #00000000

Comment: what if you put only Theme.AppCompat without light or dark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Alpha property

*Alpha* property of the view, as a value between 0 (completely transparent) and 1 (completely opaque).

XML Attributes:

```
android:alpha
```

example:

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:alpha="0"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Programatically:

```
setAlpha(float);
```

example:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.setAlpha(0);
```

[Android Developers documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha)

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your Code .

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: it's odd, remove setbackground and do getSupportActionbBar().setBackground after you set it

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to change the opacity of the background image of the toolbar. I think this will do.